# $resource $delete won't remove Resource object

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS [`$resource`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

```
App.factory("pjApi", ["$resource", function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/:user/:action/:post_id/", {action:"posts"});
}]);
```

and in my controller, I basically use it like this:

```
$scope.deletePost = function(post_id) {
    $scope.posts.forEach(function(post) {
        if (post_id === post.id)
            post.$delete({user:"tjb1982",action:"delete",post_id:post.id});
    });
}
```

The server gives a response with status 200, application/json, and body: "1"

What Angular does with this response is to remove the deleted instance of the Resource object, but then Angular replaces it with the response from the server (i.e. "1"), as if I were creating or updating:

`posts
[Resource { 0="1", $$hashKey="00D", $get=function(),  more...}]`

etc.

So my template is updated with this new (mostly blank) information, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I've tried returning nothing from the server or "0"-- returning nothing results in the Resource instance being preserved entirely and returning "0" results in the same as returning "1".

What response is Angular looking for in order for this Resource instance to be removed entirely so that my template renders correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling `$delete` on a resource only sends the HTTP request to the server; if you want to remove the item from some client side representation--such as an array--you must do so yourself.

So, for your example, you might try something like the following:

```javascript
$scope.deletePost = function(post_id) {
  $scope.posts.forEach(function(post, index) {
    if (post_id === post.id) {
      post.$delete({user:"tjb1982",action:"delete",post_id:post.id}, function() {
        $scope.posts.splice(index, 1);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I put it in the callback. Thanks for your help.  `post.$delete({user:"tjb1982", action:"delete", post_id:post.id}, function(resp){ column.posts.splice(i, 1); });`

Comment: That's a way better idea; I'm totally changing my answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
// instance is cleared on success
post.$delete({/* request data */}, function() {
    // remove empty element from array
    $scope.posts = $scope.posts.filter(function(el) {
        return el.id !== undefined;
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked well for me and is cleaner than the accepted answer IMO.